# Scalaquery: filter by “any”-combination of conditions

Tags: scala, filter, scalaquery

I want join an arbitrary-length list of filters with `or`. If the list would be fixed-length, it would look like this:

```
query.filter(filters(0) || filters(1) || … || filter(n))
```

Joining filters with `and` would be easy:

```
for (filter ← filters)
    query = query.filter(filter)
```

Joining things that evaluate to `Boolean`s with `or` is easy, too:

```
val any = evaluateToBools.foldLeft(true)(
    (left: Boolean, right: Eval2Bool) =>
    left || right.evaluate
)
```

---

## Update:

as i wrote it, it would be easy, if scalaquery’s `filter` was a standard one. unfortunately, scalaquery only allows these filters to be executed by the sql engine.

so my specific question would be:
if i have a set of string tuples:

```
val tms = Set( ("A","a"), ("B", "b"), ... )
```

and a query with the two columns “t” and “m”,

how can i generate a filter that represents the following SQL:

```
... WHERE/AND ( (t="A" and m="a") or (t="B" and m="b") or ... )
```

…or can sql `in` operators be used with tuples like this?

```
... WHERE (t,m) IN (("A","a"), ("B","b"), ...)
```

and if so, how to do it in scalaquery

---

### Hack:

currently, i do the following:

```
val tms = markers map { tm ⇒ tm._1 +"||"+ tm._2 }
query.filter(d ⇒ d._4 ++"||"++ d._5 inSet tms)
```

…but that’s unbearably hacky.

## Solution

I implemented Stefan’s solution like this:

```
rq = rq filter { d ⇒
    markers map { tm ⇒
        (d._4 is tm._1) && (d._5 is tm._2)
    } reduceLeft { _||_ }
}
```

Comment: I haven't used Scalaquery, but can't you just foldLeft the list of filters with `||`? I guess `||` returns a filter. You would need to start with a "false" filter that never matches. If you know that the list is non-empty you can just use `reduceLeft`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is really nothing about `Query.filter` which would make this any different than combining predicates for filtering a Scala collection. Yes, it does have a more complicated type:

```
def filter[T](f: E => T)(implicit wt: CanBeQueryCondition[T]): Query[E, U] = ...
```

But you can safely ignore the `CanBeQueryCondition` typeclass and assume `T` to be `Column[Boolean]` or `Column[Option[Boolean]]` as long as you use that same type for all of your predicates (which you can always do).

So what is the type of your `filters` sequence? I assume this is where your problem lies. Let's start with filtering a Scala collection `List[User]`. Here the predicates should have the type `User => Boolean` and you can reduce the applied predicates with `||` to combine them:

```
case class User(id: Int, name: String)

val users = List(
  User(1, "foo"),
  User(2, "bar"),
  User(3, "blub")
)

val filters = List(
  { u: User => u.id == 1 },
  { u: User => u.name == "bar" }
)

val filtered = users filter { u =>
  filters map { _(u) } reduceLeft { _ || _ }
}
```

Now we add a database table for these `User` objects:

```
class DBUsers extends Table[User]("USERS") {
  def id = column[Int]("ID")
  def name = column[String]("NAME")
  def * = id ~ name <> (User, User.unapply _)
}
object DBUsers extends DBUsers
```

Filtering a `Query[DBUsers]` requires predicates of type `DBUsers => Column[Boolean]`:

```
val dbFilters = List(
  { u: DBUsers => u.id === 1 },
  { u: DBUsers => u.name === "bar" }
)
```

Combining and applying the filters is exactly the same as before:

```
val dbFiltered = DBUsers filter { u =>
  dbFilters map { _(u) } reduceLeft { _ || _ }
}
```

Regarding an `inSet` method for tuples: I think it's a good idea. Please file an enhancement request for it. Some database systems could support it natively, and for the others the encoding outlined in this answer could be used.

Comment: the current `inSet` should also support Sets :D As for your answer, i’ll try to implement it and accept/reward the bounty afterwards.

Comment: oh, and `exists` and `forall` would be nice :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
query.filter(filters reduceLeft (_ || _))
```

Comment: that’s not so easy: scalaquery uses a lot of implicits, and `filters` is no actual list of filters: see the updated question