# Scala define function standard

Tags: function, scala, coding-style, definition

The following are equivalent:

```
scala> val f1 = {i: Int => i == 1}
f1: Int => Boolean = <function1>

scala> val f2 = (i: Int) => i == 1
f2: Int => Boolean = <function1>
```

I am more familiar with the former (coming from Groovy), but the latter form is much more common, AFAIK, the standard way to define a function in Scala.

Should I forget the past (Groovy) and adopt the 2nd form? The 1st form is more natural for me as it looks similar to Groovy/Ruby/Javascript way of defining closures (functions)

**EDIT**
See Zeiger's answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522960/scalaquery-filter-by-any-combination-of-conditions), for an example where groovy/ruby/javascript closure `{=>}` syntax seems more natural than `() =>` I assume both can be used interchangeably with same performance, ability to pass around, etc. and that the *only* difference is syntax

Comment: There is a third way to define function: `val f3 = (_: Int) == 1`.

Comment: ahh right, the phantom underscore, that is indeed as succinct as it gets, not to mention creating much head scratching on the part of non-Scala-ists ;-)

Comment: @senia your example does not work with {_: Int => ==1} (or 1==), so a +1 for the () => camp

Comment: If you like curly brackets you can use them: `{(_: Int) == 1}`

Comment: ha, well the curlies are pointless in that case ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this is the matter of taste (scala [styleguide](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/declarations.html#function_values) recommends first one). The former one allow you to write multiline (>2 lines in body) functions:

```
val f1 = { i: Int =>
  val j = i/2
  j == 1
}
```

Sometimes it is useful

Comment: You can write multiline functions with the second form as well: `val f = (i: Int) => { ... multiline body ... }`

Comment: +1, yes, that is "exactly" the syntax I have grown used to on the dynamic side of the fence.

Comment: @GregCampbell yes, but in scala doc, the one op provided and one you've writed treats as different types

Comment: @GregCampbell cookie monster's version is cleaner, IMO, for multi-line. Of course, my eyes filter in favor of val f = {...}. Will likely change the more I work with Scala

Answer (score 2):

Actually, both versions are simplified forms of the "full" version.

Full version: multiple parameters, multiple statements.

```
scala> val f0 = { (x: Int, y: Int) => val rest = x % y; x / y + (if (rest > 0) 1 else 0) }
f0: (Int, Int) => Int = <function2>
```

The "groovy" version: one parameter, multiple statements.

```
scala> val f1 = { x: Int => val square = x * x; square + x }
f1: Int => Int = <function1>
```

The "scala" version: multiple parameters, one statement.

```
scala> val f2 = (x: Int, y: Int) => x * y
f2: (Int, Int) => Int = <function2>
```

A version with a single parameter and a single statement does not exist, because it is not syntactically valid (ie, the grammar for that doesn't quite work).